# Is there a tool that tells me if I have unused CSS classes?

Tags: css

Imagine that I have a `<p>` element with class `title`:

```
<p class='title'>Title</p>
```

And

```
.title {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And then for whatever reason, I decide to delete `<p class='title'>Title</p>` but forget to delete the CSS rule.

Is there a tool that would show every CSS rule that is not being used in any of the project's files in order to clean up my code?

I am using Atom as my text editor. Maybe a pluggin could do that?

Comment: FYI: A cursory [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=check+css+for+unused+styles) reveals a number of promising-looking options. Although the [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/heres-the-thing-about-unused-css-tools/) article that's at the top of those search results indicates a need to be wary of using such tools. Also consider that unused styles is going to have less of a performance impact than the number of network calls (e.g. 1 style sheet with 10 unused styles is probably going to perform faster than 10 CSS files whose rules are all used).

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Paulie_D I disagree with the current policy on this. Such tools and their usage are also part of our knowledge. If it feels intuitive to ask here, it should be allowed.

Comment: You can disagree all you like but it's still off topic. If you want to change the rule take it up on meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome Devtools has [a coverage tab](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage) which can locate unused CSS and JS.
[image]

> Each line of code is color-coded:
>
> - Solid green means that line of code executed.
> - Solid red means it did not execute.
> - A line of code that is both red and green, such as line 3 in Figure    2, means that only some code on that line executed. For
>     example, a    ternary expression like var b = (a > 0) ? a : 0 is
>     colored both red    and green.